# Any RTL function to remove accents from a char?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, unicode-normalization

Nowadays with Sydney, is there any RTL function to remove accents from a char (`é` becomes `e` for exemple) in a String? I know this question was already asked in the past but I would like to know if the answers are still accurate with Sydney - I would especially love to find a function that work on all platforms (the one I use right now works only through WideString and Windows API).

Comment: What about ``StringReplace``?

Comment: I'm not aware of such function. But this doesn't mean it doesn't exists.

Comment: @DelphiCoder, the job is too huge for handle the whole Unicode charset :(

Comment: @fpiette yes me too, but I just want to ask to be sure :)

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. One could imagine that Windows, Delphi or some other Unicode-handling layer might have a built-in function for this. I am curious, too.

Comment: Many of my applications include a copy of the Unicode character name database. Using this, I could easily make an approximate function that performs this task by looking at the character names. For instance, U+00E5: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE, U+00E4: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS, U+00E3: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE, U+00E1: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE, U+00E0: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE, and U+00E2: LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX would app map to U+0061: LATIN SMALL LETTER A since their names start with this string.

Comment: Over the years [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) did a great job to me, but since it's a library you'd have to at least ship a DLL for Windows. Other systems might have installed that already. I highly doubt Delphi will re-invent what this library achieved over decades.

Comment: I use [`FoldString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-foldstringw) with `MAP_COMPOSITE` on Windows platform to get normalization form D, then remove accents. [`NormalizeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-normalizestring) is supported since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2):

Found and modified an implementation that uses `NormalizeString()` from this article:

[How to use NormalizeString function in delphi?](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/492700/how-to-use-normalizestring-function-in-delphi)

This works for me in Delphi 10.3 Rio (include `System.Character` in your `uses` clause):

```pascal
function NormalizeString(NormForm: NORM_FORM; lpSrcString: LPCWSTR; cwSrcLength: Integer; lpDstString: LPWSTR; cwDstLength: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\normaliz.dll';
    
function NormalizeText(Str: string): string;
var
  nLength: integer;
  c: char;
  i: integer;
  temp: string;
  CatStr:string;
begin
  nLength := NormalizeString(NormalizationD, PChar(Str), Length(Str), nil, 0);
  SetLength(temp, nLength);

  nLength := NormalizeString(NormalizationD, PChar(Str), Length(Str), PChar(temp), nLength);
  SetLength(temp, nLength);

  CatStr:='';
  for i := 1 to length(temp) do
  begin
    c:=temp[i];
    if (TCharacter.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> TUnicodeCategory.ucNonSpacingMark) and
      (TCharacter.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> TUnicodeCategory.ucCombiningMark) then
      CatStr:=CatStr+c;
  end;
  result:=CatStr;
end;
```

Comment: See now OP is looking for a cross-platform solution rendering my answer not solving the question. I'll leave it here for reference anyway

Comment: thanks Lars :) not cross platform but good to have !

Comment: TCharacter is deprecated since XE4, you can now use `System.Character.TCharHelper`:

So you can replace 

    `if (TCharacter.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> TUnicodeCategory.ucNonSpacingMark) and
          (TCharacter.GetUnicodeCategory(c) <> TUnicodeCategory.ucCombiningMark) then`

with 

    `if (C.GetUnicodeCategory <> TUnicodeCategory.ucNonSpacingMark) and
       (C.GetUnicodeCategory <> TUnicodeCategory.ucCombiningMark) then`

on XE4+